# How to run a dll as a service?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, dll, service

I know how to write a dll and how to write a service and how to run a dll with `rundll32`, but now I want to write a dll that install as a service in windows

I don't know if that's possible or which function in dll should be exported?

How can I install and run a dll as a service?

Comment: create a web service that references to your dll.

Comment: Googling this I found generally useful info (http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-services-wrapper.html), but I don't think any of the relevant APIs are public. So you'd have to write your own wrapper, or use undocumented stuff.

Comment: thank you, it was in the link : ***Svchost.exe : Service Host for loading dynamic-link libraries (DLL) as a services*** so if I want to run dll as a service I should use Svchost.exe? but I don't know how to use it   up to now I install my service with `sc create...` and start it in the `Services.exe`

Comment: I don't think you can expect to get svchost to host your dll. Write your own host exe.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: you CAN run your own DLL in svchost (see my answer).  That is its job, afterall.  It is just not recommended by Microsoft, as svchost is a system component meant for running Microsoft's own DLL services.  But information about interfacing with svchost is available. Microsoft even documents how to configure svchost to run a custom DLL, but conveniently omits to document what the DLL should export (a standard `ServiceMain()` function).

Comment: @RemyLebeau The advice that MS provides is clear enough. Don't expect svchost to host your DLL.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Microsoft's advice of "this should not be done" does not negate the fact that they also document HOW to do it.  So one CAN expect svchost to host a custom DLL, because Microsoft designed it to work that way. It is not locked down to just Microsoft DLLs.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I read the advice differently from you in that case

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I must be missing something - where do Microsoft document how to do it?  Your answer links to a third-party article.

Comment: @Remy **Note that Svchost.exe is reserved for use by the operating system** is clear to me. I don't know how you could interpret it the way you do.

Comment: In my opinion this question should be protected to prevent of deleting... really that's a great question.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few different ways to run a DLL as a service.  You can either:

1. Write your own .exe service and have it load your DLL as needed.  This is the recommended approach.
2. Use Microsoft's SVCHOST.EXE to host your DLL.  Have your DLL export a [`ServiceMain()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685138.aspx) function, add a `ServiceDLL` value to your service's Registry key to point at your DLL, add your service name to a new group in SVCHOST's Registry key, and then set `svchost -k <GroupName>` as the executable for your service.  See these articles for more details:

   [A description of Svchost.exe](https://web.archive.org/web/20150320155229/https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/314056)

   [Getting Started with SVCHOST.EXE Troubleshooting](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2008/01/11/getting-started-with-svchost-exe-troubleshooting.aspx)

   [Tricks with SVCHOST.EXE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/danvdw/archive/2003/09/26/51956.aspx)

   [The Service Host](http://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/win32/services/svchost/index.htm)

   Note, however, that MSDN's [Service Programs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685967.aspx) documentation warns against this approach:

   > A service program created with the type SERVICE_WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS contains code for more than one service, enabling them to share code. An example of a service program that does this is the generic service host process, Svchost.exe, which hosts internal Windows services. **Note that Svchost.exe is reserved for use by the operating system and should not be used by non-Windows services. Instead, developers should implement their own service hosting programs.**
3. Write your service as a *kernel-mode driver* that exports a [`DriverEntry()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544113.aspx) function, and add a `ServiceDLL` value in your service's Registry key pointing at the DLL file.  See this article for more details:

   [Driver Development Part 1: Introduction to Drivers](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9504/Driver-Development-Part-Introduction-to-Drivers).

   I would not recommend this approach, unless you are designing your own hardware.

Answer (score 3):

There's actually no inherent reason why you can't use `rundll32.exe` as the host executable, though use of rundll32 [isn't recommended](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/01/04/10382242.aspx).  (To expand on that: I gather you're trying to build a DLL service as an academic exercise, which is fine.  In production, you should of course use an EXE, as you've already done.)

Your main function should [have this signature](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/164787):

```
void CALLBACK MyServiceEntry(HWND hwnd, HINSTANCE hinst, LPSTR lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
```

and should call `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher`, in the same way as the `main()` or `WinMain()` function in a conventional service.

You would then install the service to use the following command line:

```
rundll32 MyService.dll,MyServiceEntry
```

For an academic exercise, it would also be acceptable to use `svchost.exe` as described in Remy's answer, but it is even more important not to use that in a production context: the use of rundll32 by third parties is supported but not recommended; the use of svchost by third parties is explicitly unsupported.