# My dll service disappears after restarting the system

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-services

I wrote a dll service in c++ with *API* functions and working properly. I implemented a `ServiceMain()` function as `dllexport` in which call `RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerW()` function to handle the incoming signals (e.g. stop, pause, ...) of my service.

Every thing working good and I defined all the necessary functions to run the service :

- `ServiceMain()` is defined and `RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerW()` calls within to register control handler.
- Set service status to `SERVICE_START_PENDING` then to `SERVICE_RUNNING` to run the service.
- I implemented a `thread` to do stuffs as service jobs and working properly.
- And I can <kbd>start</kbd> and <kbd>stop</kbd> my service.

My service is a `dll` not `exe` so I'm using `svchost.exe` to host it and I did below steps to register in windows registry:

***1. I create a new value in registry as a group to introduce my service to `svchost.exe` as following :***

[image]

***2. I create `Parameters` subkey And fill a value with my dll (service file) as following :***

[image]

***3. Also I defined a value (`ServiceMain`) due to introduce my `ServiceMain` function to `svchost.exe` as start point.***

So far, my service working even in logged off user ***BUT*** when I restart my computer, after logon to windows my service disappeared from *Windows Service Manager*. Actually it is removed from ***SCM*** database.

By the way I installed my service with `3` methods. And I'm using `svchost.exe` as `binarypath` to install the service (because `svchost.exe` behave as host for my dll  service). For example with `sc.exe` program I set `binarypath` to `svchost.exe` to run my service indirectly with `-k groupname` as parameters.

*My problem is :* ***When I restart my system then my service disappeared (is deleted) after logging in. Please help me to solve this problem.***

Comment: Why don't you register the service using the API? Why hack at the registry?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I hacked at the registry because its need to create some keys and values to introduce the service to `svchost.exe`

Comment: Where is this documented as a supported thing to do? It doesn't seem to work. Perhaps it is a valid thing and you got something wrong. In which case that should be clear once we read the documentation. Or is this unsupported and you instead need to use the service API to add a new service.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan according this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30554180/how-to-run-a-dll-as-a-service?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: *Note that Svchost.exe is reserved for use by the operating system and should not be used by non-Windows services. Instead, developers should implement their own service hosting programs.*

Comment: Just a small note regarding the images: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question